# LaTeX code not working after processing the data from a PHP file

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, mathjax

I have a WordPress website and it supports LaTeX code via the LaTeX plugin (Simple Mathjax). When I use code like `$\vec{V}$` it responds very well in the WordPress editor and prints my LaTeX code.

But when I process my data in a calculator from an external PHP file (hosted on my server) **it only processes the data** and **doesn't show the LaTeX formatting code**.

**Already Tried Things**

1. I tried - `echo "$\vec{V}$";` in the PHP file, but it doesn't print the latex formatted code.
2. I also tried to do this -> `$   <?PHP ...code file...?>  $` it also doesn't work.

**My PHP File**

```
<?php


$dateFrom = $_GET['v1'];
$dateTo = $_GET['v2'];


  
echo "$\vec{V}$ <br/>  ";

echo "Date From: ".$dateFrom."<br/>";
echo "Date To: ".$dateTo."<br/>";

?>
```

Comment: Isn't PHP then rendering it?  Is the Mathjax plugin designed to run inside of a PHP file?

Comment: I am not sure about that.

Comment: Check the output of the PHP script in the browser.. is Mathjax still downloaded? What is shown instead of the results? Nothing or the non-typeset text? If nothing, check the development tools if the element you output is in the code or not. Currently, it's hard to know if it's a Mathjax problem or a PHP problem.